# How to modify a variable {{var order.increment_id}} from transactional email

Tags: magento-1, email, transactional-mail

Does someone know where the value of {{var order.increment_id}} comes from?

The variable is in the “credit memo” template in the transactional email section.

Can someone help? Because I need to create a function and variable to apply in the transactional email but don’t where to create it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Open following class:

> app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Creditmemo.php

Check following code snippet, how magento pass the order to an email template.

```
$mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
        'order'        => $order,
        'creditmemo'   => $this,
        'comment'      => $comment,
        'billing'      => $order->getBillingAddress(),
        'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
    )
);
```

[Update]

Overwrite **Creditmemo** class:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <sales>
            <rewrite>
                <order_creditmemo>SR_MagentoCommunity_Model_Order_Creditmemo</order_creditmemo>
            </rewrite>
        </sales>
    </models>
</global>
```

> app/code/local/SR/MagentoCommunity/Model/Order/Creditmemo.php

```
<?php

class SR_MagentoCommunity_Model_Order_Creditmemo extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Creditmemo
{
    /**
     * Send email with creditmemo data
     *
     * @param boolean $notifyCustomer
     * @param string $comment
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Creditmemo
     */
    public function sendEmail($notifyCustomer = true, $comment = '')
    {
        $order = $this->getOrder();
        $storeId = $order->getStore()->getId();

        if (!Mage::helper('sales')->canSendNewCreditmemoEmail($storeId)) {
            return $this;
        }
        // Get the destination email addresses to send copies to
        $copyTo = $this->_getEmails(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_COPY_TO);
        $copyMethod = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_COPY_METHOD, $storeId);
        // Check if at least one recepient is found
        if (!$notifyCustomer && !$copyTo) {
            return $this;
        }

        // Start store emulation process
        $appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
        $initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);

        try {
            // Retrieve specified view block from appropriate design package (depends on emulated store)
            $paymentBlock = Mage::helper('payment')->getInfoBlock($order->getPayment())
                ->setIsSecureMode(true);
            $paymentBlock->getMethod()->setStore($storeId);
            $paymentBlockHtml = $paymentBlock->toHtml();
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            // Stop store emulation process
            $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
            throw $exception;
        }

        // Stop store emulation process
        $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);

        // Retrieve corresponding email template id and customer name
        if ($order->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
            $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_GUEST_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
            $customerName = $order->getBillingAddress()->getName();
        } else {
            $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
            $customerName = $order->getCustomerName();
        }

        $mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');
        if ($notifyCustomer) {
            $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
            $emailInfo->addTo($order->getCustomerEmail(), $customerName);
            if ($copyTo && $copyMethod == 'bcc') {
                // Add bcc to customer email
                foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
                    $emailInfo->addBcc($email);
                }
            }
            $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);
        }

        // Email copies are sent as separated emails if their copy method is 'copy' or a customer should not be notified
        if ($copyTo && ($copyMethod == 'copy' || !$notifyCustomer)) {
            foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
                $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
                $emailInfo->addTo($email);
                $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);
            }
        }

        $newVarObject = new Varien_Object();
        $newVarObject->setData(['new_var' => 'New Var Value']);

        // Set all required params and send emails
        $mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, $storeId));
        $mailer->setStoreId($storeId);
        $mailer->setTemplateId($templateId);
        $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
                'order'        => $order,
                'creditmemo'   => $this,
                'comment'      => $comment,
                'billing'      => $order->getBillingAddress(),
                'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml,
                'newVarObject' => $newVarObject
            )
        );
        $mailer->send();
        $this->setEmailSent(true);
        $this->_getResource()->saveAttribute($this, 'email_sent');

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNewVarFunction()
    {
        return $this->getIncrementId().'_Modified';
    }
}
```

Now in the email template, you can use the following variable:

> {{var creditmemo.new_var_function}}
>
> {{var newVarObject.new_var}}

Comment: I couldnt find that file. Do you think that is because I'm on Magento 1.9?

Comment: After Vendor, there is no magento folder.

Comment: Check updated answer, this is M1 now.

Comment: Should I create the function and variables there in order to use it in the template? Can you give me an example, I'll be very grateful. Thanks

Comment: Check updated answer